# Return a value in a column base on condition Use Ifs or Hlookup, Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I Try to return data in column J to the table, If "Number of lesson" are equal and the column name "F1,F2,F3" are equal to data in "Flow" column, and I use IF but it just apply for 1 cell, How to use IFs or other methods?

What i try:
=IF(and($C3=H4, D$2= I4),$J4,false)
[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of versions of how this can be done with one formula

сase 1: copy this formula into cell `D3`

`=ArrayFormula(sumif(H4:H15&I4:I15,C3:C11&D2:F2,J4:J15))`

[image]

case 2: if you really need to specify `False` instead of zero values, then write this formula in cell `D3`

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(sumif(H4:H15&I4:I15,C3:C11&D2:F2,J4:J15)),"^0$","False"))`

[image]